# Using Units with out circular unit reference?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have 3 units

```
-Main
-transfer
-Spell
```

What i need is for main to be able to access spell and spell to be able to access main.

So what i have tried is

```
MAIN
uses transfer;

TRANSFER
uses ;

SPELL 
uses main,transfer;
```

This way main can send data to `transfer` and `spell` can get the data from `transfer` and update `main`..

Is this a normal way of doing this? How can i do it better? There is alot of data comming from main that spell needs. Also alot of items that are changed in main from spell.

Comment: What exactly is the question? We can't really advise on anything specific because there are no details.

Comment: Is this a normal way of doing this? How can i do it better?

Comment: It is normal to put code in multiple units that use other units

Comment: that was not the question, it was "Is this a normal way of doing this?"  you forgot the way ...

Comment: Yes. It is normal. But it's impossible to tell if it's "the right way". If the classes in the `spell` unit should be standalone (independent) they should not rely on `main` unit (where I guess is the UI). But it may well not be true since I don't know your class design.

Comment: Without details you cannot expect much enlightenment. Anyway, you've accepted an answer so I guess you've found what you need.

Comment: @David I think Glen's question was aimed at a comment of mine which I deleted when I posted an answer

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks but yes i found the answer below, he seem to understand exactly what i was asking.

Comment: Yes, I guess I should have done better understanding your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on what is needed of each unit. In certain cases, you can move units to the `uses` clause at the beginning of your `implementation` section (as opposed to the beginning of your `interface`). But that all depends on what is needed.

Whenever you consider moving units to the `implementation` section, you should always ask yourself why you should have to do so. Usually cross-referencing units can lead to an overload of dependencies, and kinda defeats the purpose of creating self-contained units. For example, if you put code in a separate unit than your main form, there should be no reason that unit should refer back to the main form.

Comment: The main reason is , i just wanted it separate for ease of viewing / coding.  I could put them into one unit, but its over 5k lines together.

Comment: In that case, it can be okay, just move the form's unit to the `implementation` section.

Comment: down votes dont matter to me... i actually get alot of help from post that have been downvoted...